# when creating partition on the disk do I have to create for all the disks?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm new to this and am installing ubuntu alongisde windows (dual boot). I'm now shrinking the disk space. I have an ssd with 50 gb left and 1 tb hdd with 850gb left. I'm going to install ubuntu in the so I have to make space for it there, but do I have to also shrink the hdd so that I can access it in ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Claude Frantz's answer describes the situation, and I'll try to supplement it to give you a better understanding, but it would help in giving you a detailed answer if we better understood exactly what you've got.  Also, there's a missing important word in the question: "I'm going to install ubuntu in the", which is kind of a cliff hanger.  Read the current answers for context and then expand your question with the relevant detail.  That will allow us to expand the answers and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have to find the necessary space on disks in order to install the additional OS. If this necessary space is available in the unallocated part of the disks, there is no problem as long as the space is great enough. But if the necessary space can only the found in the unused part of existing and used partitions, it becomes necessary to shrink these partitions, but this is not always possible and such operations are risky.

I recommend to install the /home directory on a own partition. This makes upgrade more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the drive is a bucket of space.  To use that space for a particular purpose, you need some supporting infrastructure.  You use a container (partition) to define what space you're using for that purpose.  If you want to store files or an operating system, it needs a filesystem to keep track of the contents.  You format the partition to create the filesystem.

You can make the entire drive one partition, or you can divide up the space and have multiple partitions for different purposes.  On a bare drive, you can chop up the space however you want.  You can choose to leave portions untouched (unallocated), for future use; there's no requirement to create partitions everywhere at once.

If there is unallocated space, you can carve out chunks of it and create partitions when you need them.  If that unallocated space is immediately adjacent to a partition (and on the right end of it), you can resize the partition to expand into the unused space.

If you don't have any unallocated space and need an additional partition, you can often steal the space for the new partition from a partition that still has some free space in it.  You do that by shrinking the existing partition, which leaves unallocated space in which you can put a new one (or several).

Windows comes with a tool to shrink the Windows partition.  It's easy enough to use, but there's a complication and it does carry a little risk.  On a hard drive, the existing Windows files may be scattered all over the space that was originally allocated to it.  Windows also anchors some system files right in the center of that partition, so even if most of the space is still unused, you can't shrink that partition more than half without a little manual intervention to deal with those anchored files.

The risk comes mainly from the filesystem managing the area you're going to shrink.  The process of chopping off that space can leave some corruption.

So shrinking the space isn't quite as simple as just clicking a button.  You want backups to be able to recover if things go sideways.  On a hard drive (but not an SSD), you will want to do some preparation, like defragmenting the partition and its free space to get all of the content concentrated in the area that will remain, and deal with the anchored files if you need to shrink it by more than half.  After shrinking, it's a good idea to run chkdsk, even if you don't get warnings about corruption.

That will give you some context.  You can see that there are things to consider in how and where you carve out space, as well as how you divide and allocate that space for Ubuntu.  For example, you ideally should create three partitions for Ubuntu; one for the operating system (root partition), one for your files and customizations (home partition, which also provides benefits in creating backups and doing upgrades), and a swap partition, which provides some virtual memory and a place to save everything when you hibernate the system.  Also, if you will want to share files between Ubuntu and Windows, there are considerations for how best to do that.

If you expand the question with the relevant detail, people will be able to make specific recommendations.